# Finish converting password box function that calls IE from VBScript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript

For several years, I used a VBScript program to, among other things, open an Internet Explorer window to prompt me for a user ID, password, and a couple of other variables.  Recently, however, my company forced IE11 on everyone.  Even though I don't know Javascript, I decided to try converting the program by changing the file extension from .vbs to .js and fixing the errors one by one.  I eventually got the program to run without throwing an error, and it actually runs IE and displays the password box window, but when I click on the "Submit" button it crashes.  I was hoping that someone who actually knows Javascript might look at the function and tell me what the problem is.  I stripped the program down to just run the function and display the results.  Thanks in advance to all who respond.

```
var Version = "1.18";

var True = 1;
var False = 0;

var aryServers;
var intI, intLen;
var blnPwdBoxWait;
var objWShell, objIE;
var strLoginID, strPassword, setServer, strShell, strLocalUser;

aryServers = Array( "server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5" );

// ###################  DEFAULT SERVER AND SHELL VALUES
strServer = "server3";  // computer to which you will be connecting
strShell = "sh";     // "sh" if sh, bash, etc. or "csh" if csh, tcsh, etc.
// ###################

objWShell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.shell" );
strLocalUser = objWShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" );

// Get user data
strLoginID = "";
strPassword = "";
if ( strPassword == "" ) {
    strPassword = PasswordBox ( "Password Box Demo, Version " + Version );
    WScript.Sleep( 500 );
}

window.alert( "strLoginID: " + strLoginID + ", strPassword: " + strPassword +
    ", strServer: " + strServer + ", strShell: " + strShell );

objWShell = Nothing;
WScript.Quit;
// ################## 
function PasswordBox( strIETitle ) {
    objIE = new ActiveXObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" );
    objIE.FullScreen = False;
    objIE.AddressBar = False;
    objIE.MenuBar = False;
    objIE.StatusBar = False;
    objIE.ToolBar = False;
    objIE.RegisterAsDropTarget = False;
    objIE.Navigate("about:blank");

    do {
        WScript.Sleep( 100 );
    } while ( ! objIE.ReadyState == 4 );

    if ( strLoginID != "" && strPassword == "" ) {
        objIE.document.parentWindow.resizeTo( 400, 300 + 70 );
    } else {
        objIE.document.parentWindow.resizeTo( 400, 260 + 70 );
    }
    objIE.document.parentWindow.moveTo(
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.width / 2 - 200,
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.height / 2 - 200 );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<html>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<title>" + strIETitle + "</title>" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "<style type='text/css'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<!--" );
    objIE.document.writeln( ".fixed { font-family:courier new, monospace }" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "-->" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</style>" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "</head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<body bgcolor=Silver>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<form>" );
    if ( strPassword == "" ) {
        if ( strLoginID == "" ) {
            strLoginID = strLocalUser;
        } else {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<b><font color='#FF3399'>Please enter a password!</font></b><p>" );
        }
    }
    objIE.document.writeln( "<b>" + strIETitle + "</b><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<tr><td colspan=2 align=left>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Enter your username and password:<br>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Username&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input id='userid' size=20 class='fixed' " +
        "value='" + strLoginID + "'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Password&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='password' id='passwd' size=20 " +
        "class='fixed'><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Remote host:" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Shell type:" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<select name='server'><br>" );
    intLen = aryServers.length;
    for ( intI = 0; intI < intLen; intI++ ) {
        if ( strServer == aryServers[ intI ] ) {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<option value='" + aryServers[ intI ] +
                "' selected>" + aryServers[ intI ] + "<br>" );
        } else {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<option value='" + aryServers[ intI ] +
                "'>" + aryServers[ intI ] + "<br>" );
        }
    }
    objIE.document.writeln( "</select>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td valign=top>" );
    if ( strShell == "sh" ) {
        objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input " +
            "type='radio' name='shell' id='sh' checked> sh/bash/ksh<br>" );
        objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input " +
            "type='radio' name='shell' id='csh'> csh/tcsh<br>" );
    } else {
        objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input " +
            "type='radio' name='shell' id='sh'> sh/bash/ksh<br>" );
        objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input " +
            "type='radio' name='shell' id='csh' checked> csh/tcsh<br>" );
    }
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='submit' value='Submit' id='but0'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</form>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</body>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</html>" );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.scroll="no";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderStyle = "outset";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderWidth = "3px";
    objIE.document.getElementsByName( "but0" ).onClick = PasswordBox_Submit;
    objIE.document.getElementsByName( "passwd" ).focus;
    objIE.Visible = True;

    objWShell.AppActivate( strIETitle );

    blnPwdBoxWait = True;
    try {
        do {
            WScript.Sleep( 100 );
            if ( objIE.Visible ) {
                blnPwdBoxWait = blnPwdBoxWait;
            }
        } while ( blnPwdBoxWait );
    } catch( err ) {
        blnPwdBoxWait = False;
    }
    strLoginID = objIE.document.GetElementsByName( "userid" ).value;
    strPassword = objIE.document.GetElementsByName( "passwd" ).value;
    strServer = objIE.document.GetElementsByName( "server" ).Options(
        objIE.document.GetElementsByName( "server" ).selectedIndex ).text;
    if ( strServer == "" ) {
        alert( "ABORTING: Radio button 'server' not readable!" );
    }
    if ( objIE.document.GetElementsByName( "shell" ).sh.checked ) {
        strShell = "sh";
    } else if ( objIE.document.GetElementsByName( "shell" ).csh.checked ) {
        strShell = "csh";
    } else {
        alert( "ABORTING: Radio button 'shell' not readable!" );
    }
    objIE.Visible = False;
    objIE.Quit;
    objIE = Nothing;
}

function PasswordBox_Submit() {
    me.document.parentWindow.event.returnValue = False;
    blnPwdBoxWait = False;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish with your VBS/JS? Where are you sending the results to?

Comment: You should learn JavaScript. What you do cannot work. It is random programming.

Comment: The function's purpose is to let a user assign values to four text variables (strLoginID, strPassword, strServer and strShell) using a fill-out form in an IE window.  The first is set with a text entry field, the second with a password field, the third with a select field, and the last with a radio field.  This worked when I could run VBScript with IE, and is really all I need assistance with.  The program that contains the function uses those values to establish a VNC session to a Linux server (specified by strServer) from my Windows PC, if that's helpful.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the easiest solution would be to add a meta tag to the page so that it forces IE to run in compatibility mode, and therefore support vbscript. In the code below there is a comment that shows how you could do this.

But now that you've converted everything, I can understand wanting to get it working in javascript, especially since running in compatibility mode is surely a temporary fix that will be unavailable some day.

I was able to get it working with just a few changes. Most of them were fixing the case of various methods:

```
var Version = "1.18";

var True = 1;
var False = 0;

var aryServers;
var intI, intLen;
var blnPwdBoxWait;
var objWShell, objIE;
var strLoginID, strPassword, setServer, strShell, strLocalUser;

aryServers = Array( "server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5" );

// ###################  DEFAULT SERVER AND SHELL VALUES
strServer = "server3";  // computer to which you will be connecting
strShell = "sh";     // "sh" if sh, bash, etc. or "csh" if csh, tcsh, etc.
// ###################

objWShell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.shell" );
strLocalUser = objWShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" );

// Get user data
strLoginID = "";
strPassword = "";

//Maybe you meant for this to be a while loop?
if ( strPassword == "" ) {
    strPassword = PasswordBox ( "Password Box Demo, Version " + Version );
    WScript.Sleep( 500 );
}

WScript.echo( "strLoginID: " + strLoginID + ", strPassword: " + strPassword +
    ", strServer: " + strServer + ", strShell: " + strShell );

objWShell = null;
WScript.Quit();
// ################## 
function PasswordBox( strIETitle ) {
    objIE = new ActiveXObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" );
    objIE.FullScreen = False;
    objIE.AddressBar = False;
    objIE.MenuBar = False;
    objIE.StatusBar = False;
    objIE.ToolBar = False;
    objIE.RegisterAsDropTarget = False;
    objIE.Navigate("about:blank");

    do {
        WScript.Sleep( 100 );
    } while ( ! objIE.ReadyState == 4 );

    if ( strLoginID != "" && strPassword == "" ) {
        objIE.document.parentWindow.resizeTo( 400, 300 + 70 );
    } else {
        objIE.document.parentWindow.resizeTo( 400, 260 + 70 );
    }
    objIE.document.parentWindow.moveTo(
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.width / 2 - 200,
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.height / 2 - 200 );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<html>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<title>" + strIETitle + "</title>" );
    //Meta tag to force compatibility mode in IE.
    //objIE.document.writeln( "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=EmulateIE9\" />" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "<style type='text/css'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<!--" );
    objIE.document.writeln( ".fixed { font-family:courier new, monospace }" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "-->" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</style>" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "</head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<body bgcolor=Silver>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<form>" );
    if ( strPassword == "" ) {
        if ( strLoginID == "" ) {
            strLoginID = strLocalUser;
        } else {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<b><font color='#FF3399'>Please enter a password!</font></b><p>" );
        }
    }
    objIE.document.writeln( "<b>" + strIETitle + "</b><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<tr><td colspan=2 align=left>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Enter your username and password:<br>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Username&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input id='userid' size=20 class='fixed' " +
        "value='" + strLoginID + "'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Password&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='password' id='passwd' size=20 class='fixed'><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Remote host:" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Shell type:" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<select id='server'><br>" );
    intLen = aryServers.length;
    for ( intI = 0; intI < intLen; intI++ ) {
        if ( strServer == aryServers[ intI ] ) {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<option value='" + aryServers[ intI ] +
                "' selected>" + aryServers[ intI ] + "<br>" );
        } else {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<option value='" + aryServers[ intI ] +
                "'>" + aryServers[ intI ] + "<br>" );
        }
    }
    objIE.document.writeln( "</select>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td valign=top>" );
    if ( strShell == "sh" ) {
        objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input " +
            "type='radio' name='shell' value='sh' checked> sh/bash/ksh<br>" );
        objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input " +
            "type='radio' name='shell' value='csh'> csh/tcsh<br>" );
    } else {
        objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input " +
            "type='radio' name='shell' value='sh'> sh/bash/ksh<br>" );
        objIE.document.writeln( "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input " +
            "type='radio' name='shell' value='csh' checked> csh/tcsh<br>" );
    }
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='button' value='Submit' id='but0' onclick=\"submitted.value='DONE';\">" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='hidden' id='submitted' value=''>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</form>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</body>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</html>" );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.scroll="no";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderStyle = "outset";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderWidth = "3px";
    objIE.document.getElementById( "passwd" ).focus();
    objIE.Visible = True;

    objWShell.AppActivate( strIETitle );

    blnPwdBoxWait = '';
    try {
        do {
            WScript.Sleep( 100 );
            if ( objIE.Visible ) {
                blnPwdBoxWait = objIE.document.getElementById( "submitted" ).value;
            }
        } while ( blnPwdBoxWait=='' );
    } catch( err ) {
        WScript.Echo('ERROR: ' + err.message);
        blnPwdBoxWait == 'DONE';
    }
    strLoginID = objIE.document.getElementById( "userid" ).value;
    strPassword = objIE.document.getElementById( "passwd" ).value;
    strServer = objIE.document.getElementById( "server" ).options( objIE.document.getElementById( "server" ).selectedIndex ).text;
    if ( strServer == "" ) {
        alert( "ABORTING: Radio button 'server' not readable!" );
    }

    strShell = objIE.document.querySelector('input[name="shell"]:checked').value;


    objIE.Visible = False;
    objIE.Quit();
    objIE = null;

    return strPassword;
}
```